# Подскажите литературу по фракталам

Tags: фракталы, теория

Добрый вечер, товарищи. Прошу вас подсобить мне касательно теоретической части данного вопроса, а именно, я почему-то нигде не могу найти внятных формул, ну, или хотя бы каких-то заметок, которые используются для написания программ построения фракталов. Гугл выдает только какие-то поверхностные объяснения и то не по части фрактального дерева, а, например, снежинки Коха. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Википедия кишит ссылками на теорию и практику. чтоб найти код ищите все то же самое, что искали, только добавьте язык программирования в строку поиска (например delphi).
ваш вопрос слишком расплывчат. теория начинается с множеств Мандельброта и Жюлиа. фрактальное дерево - это как раз от снежинки Коха надо идти, не далеко. L-системы и так далее.

Online генератор http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/lsystems/